# Differential of sin x series confusion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I have been trying to figure out where I am going wrong in finding the fourth oreder differential of sin x. My issue is with the factorial, I have a feeling there must be a way to sumplyfiy it but I just cant figure out how to manipulate it.

Here is the question:

Substitute the power series for sin x into the differential equation

$$\frac{d^4y}{dx^4}=y$$

So by using the series solution for sin(x) which is:

$$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}$$

so 
$$y'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}$$

$$y''=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)!}x^{2n-1}$$

$$y'''=\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-2)!}x^{2n-2}$$

$$y''''=\sum_{n=4}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-3)!}x^{2n-3}$$

This is always an issue of mine is how do I get the series to work for me so normally I would say let $m=n-4$ and then $m+4=n$ using this method make the seris start at m=0 so like this

$$y''''=\sum_{m=0}^\infty =\frac{(-1)^(m+4}{(2(m+4)-3)!}x^{(2(m+4)-3)}$$

But this dose not simplyify to sinx at all, I always seem to get confused with the type of problem, could some please explain a method or how to solve these type of problems. I cant help but think I should be mainpulating the factorial some how but I am not sure how.

Any help would be much apprectiaed.

Comment: Isn't $$y'=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}$$

Comment: Why do you say that I if I take the differntial of a series I shif it one place to the right i.e n=1

Comment: Jason, it doesn't always work like that, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake when you first take derivative:

$$y' \neq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}$$ but rather

$$y' = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}.$$

You can easily see that from

$$(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\ldots)' = 1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\ldots$$

With that correction in mind, we now have that

$$y'' = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)!}x^{2n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1} = -y.$$

Finally, $y'''' = (-y)'' = y$.

---

*Addendum:* When you differentiate power series, starting index doesn't necessarily shift, as we can see in our examples. So, how do we know whether to shift or not?

Well, it's rather simple, when we differentiated $y$, we got $a_nx^{2n}$ and $2n\geq 0$ for $n\geq 0$, so there is no shift needed. On the other hand, when we differentiated $y'$, we got $b_nx^{2n-1}$, but $2n-1\not\geq 0$ for $n = 0$, so we need to shift.

Comment: I am slightly confused to why you say it dose not always work like? Are what you saying is this that for this trig series of sin(x) that when you take the derivative the postion of the series does not change. So for sinx we start at n=0 so when you take the derivative of the sumnation you will still start at n=0 beacuse of 1?

Comment: Ah okay I have just seen your previous comment, thank you for the explanation

Comment: You are welcome, @Jason, hopefully, it is clear now. It is customary to upvote an answer you find useful, and accept an answer that you find the most useful. You don't have to hurry with accepting an answer, but at some point, please do.

Comment: I have now confused myself how did you go from$$:y'' = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)!}x^{2n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1} = -y$$. How is it you have shifted two places

Comment: Ignor the perivous comment I am just having a bad day

Comment: @Jason, it's ok. Take some rest and come back to the problem later :)